# What is a good place to ask testing "meta" questions?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I'm seeing a lot of "meta" questions about software testing lately. These are questions like, "What do I need to know to become a tester?", "How do testers do their work?", and "How well do I need to be able to code to be a good automation tester?" These sorts of meta questions are not appropriate for Stack Overflow, but there isn't another Stack Exchange site where this really fits. Where should questions like this be directed?

I will accept an answer in about two days.  I want to give people time to answer.

Comment: This is to replace the previously poorly-handled question.  Thanks to the community for the feedback.

Comment: should this be asked on meta?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I expect answers to be succint, and discussion to be low, plus I don't think QA people tend to spend much time on meta.  I hunted around a bit, and only found one un-ambiguously QA-testing question, and it had just one answer.

Comment: Putting the sites I know about in a comment:  http://softwaretestingclub.com, and (just found this one from a comment on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39460/unit-testing-here-or-somewhere-else) http://bugoverflow.com.  I've been using the former site because it was the best thing I'd found so far, but the latter site looks even better (at a glance).  Both sites are relatively immature.

Comment: Since I asked this question so many years ago, sqa.stackexchange.com became an active thing and works very well for many of these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Accepted this answer, but I would encourage people to read Alan's comment below as well.  Thanks, vic

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted programmers since I think it's the best choice right now. Several career testers hang out there, so you would probably get a good answer.

We have a SE 1.0 site (testing.stackexchange.com), but the traffic is pretty light, so you may not get a great answer. We're working through a 2.0 proposal combining a few communities, so hopefully there's a better answer in the long term.

Comment: Thanks, Alan.  I appreciate hearing a bit more of an explanation about this.  I had looked over programmers.se, but hadn't found much evidence of good tester knowledge.  You've encouraged me to give it another try.

Comment: I wanted to add . . . I'm liking testing.stackexchange.com much better right now, despite the low traffic.  I am interested in the 2.0 answer, if it ever happens.  I don't actually have any specific questions to ask; I just like being part of a community and have been looking on-and-off for a good software test community for years.